# In eXist, how can I run an expression on a dynamically determined collection?

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I have a query that dynamically determines a collection name and an expression to evaluate on that collection that return a boolean. Say:

- `$my-collection` points to the collection, e.g. containing the string `/db/my/collection`.
- The boolean expression is `exists(/foo/bar)`.

I can run `exists(/foo/bar)` on the collection itself, which will return either true or false, depending on whether a document in the collection contains a `/foo/bar`. But how can I do the same when the collection name isn't known in advance?

Naively, I tried `collection($my-collection)/exists(/foo/bar)`. But since [`collection()`](http://demo.exist-db.org/exist/functions/fn/collection) returns the document nodes in the collection, this would return as many booleans as there are documents in the collection, instead of just one boolean. This isn't what I want, plus it can be extremely slow as my collection can contain several tens of thousands of documents.

So, how should I write this instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your expression to this:

```
exists(collection($my-collection)/foo/bar)
```

Or perhaps this, which - depending on the eXists query optimizer - might perform better:

```
exists((collection($my-collection)/foo/bar)[1])
```

HTH!